# Javascript - Editing Form with Fetch

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, fetch-api

I'm trying to edit an existing form on my site, and save the edits using Javascript (without requiring a refresh of the page). I'm using Django as well.

So far, when the user clicks 'edit' on the page, the form appropriately appears, showing the information already saved there. But when I click 'save' I get a 404 error.
The issue is in the Javascript function edit_post. I'm not sure if I have used stringify correctly either, I'm new to using Javascript with Django. Any help is appreciated.

```
function edit_handeler(element) {
  id = element.getAttribute("data-id");
  document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector(`#post-content-${id}`).style.display = "none";
  // everything above this works and opens up the form for editing

  edit_btn = document.querySelector(`#edit-btn-${id}`);
  edit_btn.textContent = "Save";
  edit_btn.setAttribute("class", "text-success edit");
  if (edit_btn.textContent == "Save") {
  edit_post(id, document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).value); //here

  edit_btn.textContent = "Edit";
  edit_btn.setAttribute("class", "text-primary edit");
}}

function edit_post(id, post) {
  const body = document.querySelector(`#post-content-${id}`).value;

  fetch("/edit_post/", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
    body:body
    })

  }).then((res) => {
    document.querySelector(`#post-content-${id}`).textContent = post;
    document.querySelector(`#post-content-${id}`).style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).value = post.trim();
  });
}
```

Relevant html - this is inside a card, for the post itself in the html file:

```
<span id="post-content-{{i.id}}" class="post">{{i.text}}</span> <br> 
                <textarea data-id="{{i.id}}" id="post-edit-{{i.id}}" 
style="display:none;" class="form-control textarea" row="3">{{i.text}}</textarea>

 <button class="btn-btn primary" data-id="{{i.id}}" id="edit-btn-{{i.id}}" 
 onclick="edit_handeler(this)" >Edit</button> <br><br>
```

views.py

```
def edit_post(request, pk):

    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = PostForm(instance=post)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return JsonResponse({}, status=201) # this works to edit and save to db
    else:
        if request.method == "GET":           
            form = PostForm(instance=post)
            form_for_post = {'form': PostForm()}
  
            return render(request, "network/make_post.html", {
                "post": post,
                "form_for_post": form,
    })
```

urls.py (relevant ones)

```
path('edit_post/<str:pk>/', views.edit_post, name="edit_post"),
path('edit_post/', views.edit_post),
path("profile/<str:username>", views.profile, name="profile"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running your django server locally and you're getting a 404 returned from your fetch request, then that means the url path does not exist. Either your django server isn't live or the url you're supplying the fetch request with is incorrect. If `/edit_post/` is your desired endpoint, try fetching with the servers full request URL

Something like this
`http://localhost:8000/edit_post`

Replace 8000 with whatever port your server is running at.

Your fetch body is structured properly btw.

Comment: thanks! I think it's the url. When I insert http://localhost:8000/edit_post (with my port inserted) into my fetch, I get 500 internal server error. So when I go to that actual url in my address bar, I get TypeError at /edit_post/
edit_post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk' but I cannot figure out why. Do I need to pass pk into my javascript file or anything like that? If I add pk into the js function like this, it still gives 500 internal server error: function edit_post(id, post, pk)